# Hyper-v wont disable

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

my Virtual machine is getting errors that conflict with hyper-v, i have disabled hyper-v and it continues to give me the errors, i have set hyper v to off in cmd, turned it off in windows features, but i am still getting this error.

here is the windows features window:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ8B9.png

Here is the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOMin.png

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt as administrator
Run bcedit
Look at the hypervisorlaunchtype, it should be set to auto.

```
bcdedit /sethypervisorlaunchtype off
```

to disable Hyper-v.
Restart the computer.
Normally it should work.